# Regex for remove all string except an range of specific characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need your help to remove all characters using a Javascript Regex in string HTML Document **except** `<body></body>` and **whole string inside** body tag.

I tried to use this but doesn't work:

```js
var str = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>my content</body></html>"
str.replace(/[^\<body\>(.+)\<\\body\>]+/g,'');
```

I need the body content only, other option will be to use `DOMParser`:

```
var oParser = new DOMParser(str);
var oDOM = oParser.parseFromString(str, "text/xml");
```

But this throws an error parsing my string document loaded via Ajax.
Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: I need this only: `<body>my content</body>` :)

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex in 3.. 2..

Comment: 1.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags  @Marty

Comment: @Marty Would you really recommend an HTML parser for something as simple as this? This is not an HTML parsing question; it's a simple matching question.

Comment: @Doorknob Actually that is exactly the reason I mentioned that those comments were coming rather than making it myself.

Comment: @joseluisq: The trouble with all the answers that are using `.*?` is that it doesn't match newline characters. In place of that, use `[\s\S]*?`

Comment: @squint yes, I tried to use [\s\S]*? and works fine thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>my content</body></html>"

str=str.match(/<(body)>[\s\S]*?<\/\1>/gi);

//also you can try this:
//str=str.match(/<(body)>.*?<\/\1>/gis);
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/VIY7fIaqJEeZXE3v)

Comment: @joseluisq see my updates:   `str=str.match(/<(body)>[\s\S]*?<\/\1>/gi);`         http://regex101.com/r/eJ6sG4/3

Answer (score 1):

You could try this code,

```
> var str = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>my content</body></html>"
undefined
> str.replace(/.*?(<body>.*?<\/body>).*/g, '$1');
'<body>my content</body>'
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rW9rL6/1)

Comment: @joseluisq try `str.replace(/[\S\s]*?(<body>.*?<\/body>)[\S\s]*/gm, '$1');`

Answer (score 0):

You can't (or at least shouldn't) do this with `replace`; try `match` instead:

```
var str = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>my content</body></html>"
var m = str.match(/<body>.*<\/body>/);
console.log(m[0]); //=> "<body>my content</body>"
```

If you have a multiline string, change the `.` (which does not include `\n`) to `[\S\s]` (not whitespace OR whitespace) or something similar.

Comment: Ok, so how can I do when the string html is more complex  http://regex101.com/r/eJ6sG4/1 ?

Comment: @joseluisq That string has newlines; you'll need the `s` flag (dotall) for that

Comment: @Doorknob there isn't a `s` modifier in js.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Whoops, that's what I get for answering JS questions while coding in Python. :P I'll edit the answer